# How to get data from different WRDS libraries

Tags: sql, stata

I know how to get access to data in Stata from a specific WRDS library.

For example:

```
odbc load, exec("select permno, shrcd, date, prc, vol, ret from crsp.dsf where date between '1995-01-01' and '1995-12-31'") dsn("wrds-pgdata-64")
```

However, I also want to get the share code, which is from library `CRSP_NAMES`, not `dsf`.

How can I tell Stata to get all the data in one batch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following `join` of the two databases should work:

```
odbc load, exec("select d.permno, n.shrcd, d.date, d.prc, d.vol, d.ret from crsp.dsf as d inner join crsp.dsenames as n on d.permno = n.permno where d.date between '1995-01-01' and '1995-12-31'") dsn("wrds-pgdata-64")
```

This assumes that the share code is `shrcd` and you want to get it based on the `permno`.